# How to call functions from external DLL using LLVM IRBuilder?

Tags: llvm

How to call functions from external DLL from LLVM? How to call a function defined in a DLL file from a LLVM code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your question is missing vital information, I can guess that you want to achieve the following. I am guessing you will be using the c/c++ interface and that the function has a signature `void fun(void)`. I also guess that you will be using LLVM Builder to create calls to this very function (and not clang or the like).

Start by using `dlopen` / `loadlibrary` to dynamically load the function and get the function pointer `fnPtr`.

Create a `Type*` for the function's return value

```
Type* voidType[1];
voidType[0] = Type::getVoidTy(getGlobalContext());
ArrayRef<Type*> voidTypeARef (voidType, 1);
```

Create a `Function*` for the function. You should have a `Module* TheModule` already from initialization phase.

```
FunctionType* signature = FunctionType::get(voidTypeARef, false);
Function* func = Function::Create(signature, Function::ExternalLinkage, "fun", TheModule);
```

Use `addGlobalMapping` to create a Mapping to the function. You should have a `ExecutionEngine* TheExecutionEngine` from initialization phase.

```
TheExecutionEngine->addGlobalMapping(func, const_cast<void*>(fnPtr));
```

Now, at the appropiate place where you want to call, you can now insert calls to the function using `IRBuilder` like this.

```
Function *FuncToCall= TheModule->getFunction("fun");
std::vector<Value*> Args; // This is empty since void parameters of function
Value *Result = IRBuilder->CreateCall(FuncToCall, Args, "calltmp"); // Result is void
```